# Binary Addition VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binary, addition

I would like to ask some help about **Binary addition** in Visual Basic 2010  .[user2471711](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029897/comments-on-binary-addition-program-in-visual-basic) created a Console Application and it works well, eventually, I would like this to be in a Windows Form Application. Do you guys have an idea on how I can make this in a WinForms application?

```
Dim a As Integer = 8
Dim b As Integer = 2
Dim c As Integer = 10

Sub Main()
    Dim binary1 As Integer
    Dim binary2 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("-------BINARY ADDITION--------")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter in your two binary numbers")
    Console.WriteLine("1st number")
    binary1 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("2nd number")
    binary2 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine(binary1 & "+" & binary2 & "=")
    binary1 = binary1 + binary2
    Console.Write(add(binary1))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Function add(ByVal x As Integer)
    For y As Integer = 1 To 8
        If x Mod c >= b Then
            x = x + a
        End If
        a = a * 10
        b = b * 10
        c = c * 10
    Next

    Return x
End Function
```

Comment: There is no difference between a console app or a WinForms app in this context. What exactly are you having a problem with in WinForms?

Comment: thank you for editing Mr. Ahmed. My professor told me to create a vb.net winform app which is a binary calculator (+/- only). I found user2471711 code but it's in console , since i cannot find other codes in the internet for this kind of  topic, I've decided to ask here. Hoping some could help me

Comment: If you don't know how WinForms works, you should be looking for WinForms tutorials. StackOverflow isn't the right place to be looking for tutorials but [here's a good place to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/getting-started-with-windows-forms) anyway. As about the code in this case, whatever works for a console app also works for WinForms _with the right tools_, that is, you'll need to use TextBoxes and MessageBoxes, for example, instead of the `ReadLine()` and `WriteLine()` methods.

Comment: I've already successfully created a Winform app which is a Binary Converter (To Bin and To Hex ViceVersa). This is just the real deal of my problem . The binary addition also with subtraction so I'm asking help to you guys :( . Maybe my question was wrong if only i just can change it o " How can I make this code into a Winform App? "

Comment: Readline() is the input in Textbox1.Text and Writeline is for the result then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Winforms put two TextBoxes, a Label, and a Button.
This code will do what your want, place it in the Button "Click' event.

```
        Dim BinaryResult As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2)
    Label1.Text = BinaryResult.ToString
```

This will sum the values entered in the textboxes and display the result in the Label when you click the button.

*** Additional formats *** ('binary' 'normal' 'hex')

```
        Label1.Text = String.Format("Base-2:{0}    Base-10:{1}    Base-16:{2}",
                                Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 2),
                                Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 10),
                                Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 16).ToUpper)
```

**However... Be warned, there is no checking here. You should check the textboxes contain what you expect but this should get you started.**

Comment: tried it and it gives me an integer answer eg. 0100 + 1010 = 14. Must be 01110 right?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that is what you wanted, my bad. Just change the last line to: Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(BinaryResult, 2)

Comment: i'll just do the checking :D tnx again

Comment: last question pls any idea on a binary to text/hexa and vice versa too please? love your simple and yet amazing short code

Comment: Tnx again btw forgot to ask this, whats the max length of an input?